# Different results from Math.pow()

Tags: java

Could someone please explain me why I am getting different results when I am calculating the pow()?

```
    double testOne = Math.pow(10, ((10 - 20) / (10 * 2)));
    System.out.println("Test One: " + testOne);

    double c = 10-20;
    double d = 10*2;
    double f = c/d;
    double testTwo = Math.pow(10, f);
    System.out.println("Test Two: " + testTwo);
```

Here are the results:

```
Test One: 1.0
Test Two: 0.31622776601683794
```

Comment: `(10 - 20) / (10 * 2)` yelds an `int` result. `c/d` yelds a `double` result. This means that decimals are trimmed out in the first one, but they aren't in the second one.

Comment: Off to find the dupetarget. In the first one, you're using integer division. In the second, you're using double division.

Comment: th expression ((10 - 20) / (10 * 2)) is interger calculations, hece, it translates into -10/20, thus when converted to is 0. Any number raise to power 0 is 1.  hence first number is 1.0.

Comment: If you debug your code, the result of the `(10 - 20) / (10 * 2)` is `0`. So `pow(10,0)` results to `1`. but in the second case `pow(10,-0.5)` so results to `0.31622776601683794`.